# How to get exact match using fnFilter?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using fnFilter in datatables and while trying to filter "inv" everything else starting with "inv" also get filtered. that is "invc", "invk" are also showing in filtered result. How to solve this and get the exact matches only?

code:

```
$("#user-lock-status-filter select").change(function() {
        oUserTable.fnFilter($(this).val(), 12);
    });
```

Comment: What does `fnFilter` do?

Comment: it's for filtering data in a column.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Change this

```
oUserTable.fnFilter($(this).val(), 12);
```

to

```
oUserTable.fnFilter("^"+$(this).val()+"$", 12, false, false); 
//disabling smart search/regex and apply your own search
```

[Example](http://datatables.net/examples/api/regex.html)

[Doc](http://datatables.net/api)

Params for `fnFilter`

```
1.{string}: String to filter the table on
2.{int|null}: Column to limit filtering to
3.{bool} [default=false]: Treat as regular expression or not
4.{bool} [default=true]: Perform smart filtering or not
5.{bool} [default=true]: Show the input global filter in it's input box(es)
6.{bool} [default=true]: Do case-insensitive matching (true) or not (false)
```

Comment: It's not working, I'm still getting "invc" rows in "inv" search.

Comment: trying to achieve this and quite confused... what is the `^` and `$` for?

Comment: @Damon, this is the regex (Regular Expression) that will be used to filter the table. ^ means the beginning of the string, and $ means the end of it. So ^searched$ will match lines containing exactly 'searched' only.

Comment: Thanks! I think my primary confusion was that you have to set 'treat as regular expression' to false in order treat it as a regular expression...

Comment: yea, I'm confused by this too.. so why 'treat as regular expression' to false?

Comment: so i think the solution is kind of wrong.. either disable smart filtering and regex and use the normal search string OR write a regex and set 'treat as regular expression' to true

Comment: What is `ouserTable`? think it's a datatable varibale. But i have used `$('.dataTable').dataTable();` to form a jquery datatable.

Comment: Confusion expected. These are some of the worst naming conventions in the world.