# Datatables search functionality

Tags: javascript, search, datatables

I use Datatables to build up a table and to make it searchable.

```
$('#table').DataTable({
    "paging" :      true,
    "info" :        true,
    "bFilter" :      true,
});
```

I have a column, which contains the values "security" and "non-security". If I search for "security"... it matches of cause to both.

**My Question** is: How to use or how to configure datatables, that the search will filter out "non-security" items when searching for "security"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DataTable plugin, by default sets the "smart" option to true. Set it to false.

```
    $('#table').DataTable({
        "paging" : true,
        "info"   : true,
        "search": {
            "smart": false
        }
    });
```

Update:

I think it's already answered here.
[How to get exact match using fnFilter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19114586/how-to-get-exact-match-using-fnfilter)

Comment: This does not change anything :(